# Is there something wrong in #define and &&

Tags: c, syntax, macros

I wonder if this would be a bad idea to makes such defines in C:

```
#define and &&
#define or  ||
#define not !
```

Comment: readability to people who aren't familiar with C. It'll probably reduce readability for people who are familiar with C, because in practice almost nobody uses them. People who are extremely familiar with the odd corners of C will at least recognise them as coming from a standard header. Probably. But recognition doesn't mean it'll read better.

Comment: I think you forget to add `#define BEGIN {` and `#define END }` to your list...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would definitely be a bad idea to do this yourself.

If you really want names like `and` instead of symbols like `&&`, you can include the `<iso646.h>` C Standard Library header, which defines several named operators, including the three you mention.

In C++, the alternative representations (like `and` and `or`) are operators built into the language, so you don't need to include any header to use them, and it isn't possible to define them as macros (a macro name must be an identifier, and the alternative representations are operators, not identifiers, even during preprocessing).

Comment: That's standard, but the least who would object to doing this yourself would consider `#include <iso646.h>` a better idea...

Comment: Flashback to a wasted afternoon for me.  Developer A decides, hey, I'll replace all instances of `&&` with `and`, `||` with `or`, etc.  For some reason this is causing conflicts somewhere else, so developer B removes the `#define`s and does a `s/and/&&/g`, `s/or/||/g` on the source and checks in back in.  You can see where this is going.  Keywords like `for` are now `f||`, instances of `and` and `or` in the comments are now `&&` and `||`, variable and function names are munged, the whole nut.  I had to grovel through the affected files line by line to fix everything.  Don't do this.

Comment: @John should have used `'s/\<and\>/&&/g'` and `'s/\<or\>/||/g'` =)

Comment: @SiegeX: *Should* have, but didn't.  And I got to clean up afterwards.